# Cannot find method

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

Hi I have object which contains method:

```
{Boolean Deserialize(System.String, HardwareItemDescriptionControlDriver ByRef)}
```

when i am trying to find this method:

```
 Type elementType = typeof(HardwareItemDescriptionControlDriver);

 typesParameters = new Type[] { typeof(String), elementType.MakeByRefType() };
 methodInfo = elementType.GetType().GetMethod("Deserialize", typesParameters);
```

methodInfo is null

I cant see where can be the problem - I also tryied to find this method with parameters:

```
typesParameters = new Type[] { typeof(String), elementType };
```

but it doesnt work neither, thanks!

Comment: does `elementType.GetType().GetMethods()` contain the method, is the method public, is it static?

Comment: Can we see the actual signature? For example: is it internal? private? protected? public? Is it instance vs static? Seeing the actual signature for Deserialize would be handy

Comment: your object which contain `Deserialize` method is `HardwareItemDescriptionControlDriver`? I'm asking because you pass same type of object as an argument in this method which is pretty weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a redundant `GetType()`; `elementType` is *already* the `Type`:

```
 methodInfo = elementType.GetMethod("Deserialize", typesParameters);
```

With the extra `GetType()`, you are asking whether `System.Type` (or more likely, `RuntimeType`) has that method (which: it doesn't).